# Using php to find files modified or created in the last day

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a cron job that will provide me with a list of files in a directory that have been created or modified in the last day. For the life of me I can't see what is wrong with the code snippet below. It produces nothing and I know that I've updated at least one file in the last 24 hours.

```
<?php

$dir = opendir(".");


clearstatcache();

while(false != ($file = readdir($dir)))
{

if ( substr($file,-4) == ".php" ) 
{
    //echo $file;
    //echo "<br>";

    $yesdate = date('d.m.Y',strtotime("-1 days"));

    if (date("d.m.Y", filemtime($file))==$yesdate)
    {

        echo $file;

    }
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: If you fix your indents it will make the source more readable.

Comment: Did any of the provided solutions worked?

Comment: Yes, yours was perfect, thank you (apologies for the late reply, I have only just got home)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get files edited in last 24 hours than you need to use `>=` instead of `==` and compare timestamp instead of dates, like:

```
$dir = opendir(".");
clearstatcache();
$yesdate = strtotime("-1 days");
while(false != ($file = readdir($dir)))
{
    if ( substr($file,-4) == ".php" ) 
    {
        if (filemtime($file) >= $yesdate)
        {
            echo $file;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will only find the files updated yesterday. If you want the last 24 hours, you could subtract the filemtime(..) from the current time. You will find the difference in seconds:

```
$now = time(); //you should put this outside of the loop
if ($now - filemtime($file) < 24 * 60 * 60)
{   
   //do something
}
```